In a 2d coordinate plane, how can I find the position of point S given the angles to 3 known reference grid points on the x and y axis.
I need to understand how to find the position of a mobile robotic camera that is positioned in a defined grided area. I rotate the camera so that it points at 3 different grid reference points named B, N and C and I have measured how much I have rotated the camera between the sightings.
The camera is now at an unknown position S. I need to calculate the grid coordinates of that position.
Here is the data and measurements;-
The x,y coordinates of point B are 0,5. It is on the positive y axis
The x,y coordinates of point N are 15,0. It is on the positive x axis
The x,y coordinates of point C are 0,10. It is on the positive y axis
( editing note;- I corrected my typing error regarding the coordinates of C on June 29th )
The angle BSN is equal to 110.6 degrees.
The angle CSB is equal to 34.6 degrees.
I believe there are two possible solution answers, one for a position where both the x and y values for S are both positive ( in the first quadrant ) and another solution in the second quadrant , where x is negative ) ?
I only need to understand how to get the position in the first quadrant.
I'll then later use the method to calculate coordinates for other positions and part of ongoing efforts to drive and steer the robotic camera.

Is $C$, $(10,0)$ or $(0,10)$ ?

This would be much easier if the three known points were $N = (0,5),B = (0,0), C = (5, 0)$.  But if you cannot control the locations of your reference points, it is still solvable. You just have to handle more complicated equations.

the corrected coordinates for C are ;- 0,10. It is on the positive Y axis. Many thanks for pointing that typing error out. I appreciate your good help. How can I calculate the position of point S in the grid ?
